# Во время установки yolo v4 возникает ошибка по не нахождению hetopt.c

Tags: python

во время сборки yolo_cpp_dll в visual studio возникает ошибка
C1083|Не удается открыть файл источник: ……\src\getopt.c: No such file or directory,|yolo_cpp_dll| D:\yolov4\darknet\build\darknet\c1|1||

Я понимаю что не хватает файла getopt.c, в интернете я нашел этот файл но куда конкретно его вставить я не знаю